# Evernote integration in ios

Tags: iphone

i am doing a reder application which can sync note to evernote,i found the API and sample code i integrate it my application and cotomize it according to out needs.and i create a sandbox useraccount for checking app before production service.in the evernoteclass.m we need to give the username and password by static there is a code like this

```
#import "Evernote.h"
NSString * const username = @"usernme";
NSString * const password = @"pswrd123"; 

NSString * const userStoreUri = @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user";
NSString * const noteStoreUriBase = @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/"; 
@implementation Evernote
```

but i need to implement this by using username and password textfield like our login page.
by add ing this value staticly i am able to send note to evernote
how to give the username dynamically using textfileds.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest [evernote ios sdk](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios), you can get authentication by oauth.

```
// set up Evernote session singleton
[EvernoteSession setSharedSessionHost:EVERNOTE_HOST 
                          consumerKey:EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_KEY 
                       consumerSecret:EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_SECRET];
EvernoteSession *session = [EvernoteSession sharedSession];
[session authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error || !session.isAuthenticated) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                         message:@"Could not authenticate" 
                                                        delegate:nil 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        DLog(@"Evernote auth ready");
        [self _authDidCompleted];
    } 
}];
```

Comment: #ifdef DEBUG
#define EVERNOTE_HOST @"sandbox.evernote.com"
#else
#define EVERNOTE_HOST @"www.evernote.com"
#endif

Answer (score 0):

Create two Textfields, One for Username and the other for password. Create IBOutlets as well. Then you can write the following code

```
NSString * const username = textField1.text;
NSString * const password = textField2.text;
```

I dont really know if u got your question correctly. But, hope this helps.....

Comment: @A for Alpha ,but evernote.h is a nsobject how can i create a textfiled in nsobject?is this possible.